# Is my character an intellectual or detective or both?

Tags: characters, character-development

My character has a habit (or running gag) of pointing out plot holes in conversations with her friends who lie a lot.                             She is quick to tell them what fragment of their stories about what they had just done recently doesn't make sense. She knows when they are lying about something as if she is Sherlock Holmes.

But Sherlock Holmes was made of two things according to a Wikipedia article of the character's category sections

1. Intellectual
2. Detective

Which is my character most likely to be clarified as?

Comment: 3. Annoying ` `

Comment: How does an accurate label for her impact the story? (I'm guessing it doesn't matter.) Characters might call her things, but their classifications don't have to be accurate; they'll just reflect their own personalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sherlock Holmes is famous for *deducing* answers to puzzles from observation. He was widely and deeply read, although he also deliberately forgot information which he felt wasn't important. He was a detective because the matters brought to him were problems which needed investigating — often crimes, but not always.

An intellectual is someone who is intelligent and studied, but not necessarily someone who is greatly observant or someone who can deduce facts given those observations.

So if your character knows that Bill is lactose intolerant but he says he was drinking milkshakes with Suzy, she can call him out on that lie. That's being a detective. If Bill starts going on about the benefits of supply-side economics and she counters with examples of Kansas's distastrous budget, that's being intellectual.

Comment: Exactly, you can be intelligent without being an intellectual. Sherlock absorbed the information needed in order to make him a better detective--details like the shape of shoe soles, the type of dirt/clay in various parts of London, and making a study of more than 100 types of cigarette ash. He did not absorb information about the solar system and the fact that we go round the sun because it's not relevant to solving murders.  Also, Bill totes could have taken Suzy to get milkshakes. She's not the one who is lactose intolerant. :)

Comment: @ErinThursby you're right about the milkshakes; I should fix that to make my point clearer. :)